# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, orm

Есть 3 сущности - репетитор, студент, группа, все связаны друг с другом через многие ко многим. Решил сделать так: объявляю **статическую** переменную **`groupForSave`**, и в неё ложу группу из БД либо болванку для новой группы. При добавлении нового студента, с помощью ajax добавляю нового студента в список **`groupForSave.Students`**, при редактировании соответственно изменяю объект коллекции **`groupForSave.Students`**. Фактически все коллекции группы изменяются в **`groupForSave`**. В самом конце, при сохранении изменений, вызываю Update/Create передав сформированный groupForSave.

**Проблема** Не могу создать новую группу, см. код, строчка в самом начале, ошибка падает даже при том, что в группе нету ни одного студента, единственное указан репетитор, остальные связи пустые.

**Мои догадки** Возможно, когда я беру репетитора контроллер в методе `Create` из репозитория, каким-то образом его контекст не уничтожается. Пробовал заменить во всех репозиториях `private dbontext = new EfDbCOntext()` на `using` получил ошибку, что пробую использовать объект из несуществующего контекста, в том же месте при добавлении группы.

```
//entity framework часть
class GroupRepository {
    dbContext = new EfDbContext(); //Ошика как-то связана с контекстами
    //упрощено, ошибка при добавлении новой записи
    public Group Create(Group obj) {
        dbContext.Groups.Add(obj); //Здесь падает ошибка
    }
}

/*
... Классы-репозитории с аналогичным методом Create для остальных сущностей(entity)
*/

class Group {
    public virtual List<Tutor> Tutors;
    public virtual List<Student>  Students;
}

class Student {
    public virtual List<Group> Groups;
    public virtual List<Tutor> Tutors;
}

class Tutor {
    public virtual List<Group> Groups;
    public virtual List<Student> Students;
}

    //Контроллер
    GroupController() {
         GroupRepository groupRepository = new GroupRepository();
         TutorRepository tutorRepository = new TutorRepository();
         StudentRepository studentRepository = new StudentRepository();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        //because id is 0 we should define if we need to create new student or it aleady exists in database
        var stud = studentRepository.GetByMail(student.Email);
        if(stud != null)
        {
            student = stud;
        }else
        {
            student.ID = idCounter++;
        }
        groupForSave.Students.Add(student);
        return Json(student);
    }

    public ActionResult Create(int tutorId)
    {
        EditGroupViewModel model = new EditGroupViewModel();
        groupForSave = new Group();
        groupForSave.Journals = new List<Journal>();
        groupForSave.Students = new List<Student>();
        groupForSave.Tutors = new List<Tutor>();
        groupForSave.Tutors.Add(tutorRepository.GetById(tutorId));
        model.name = "Новая группа " + groupRepository.GetTutorGroups(tutorId).Count();
        model.tutorId = tutorId;
        redirectAfterCreate = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
        return View("Edit", model);
    }

    public JsonResult Save(Group group)
    {
        //return Json(group, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        groupForSave.Name = group.Name;
        groupRepository.CreateWithContext(groupForSave, tutorRepository.Context);
        return Json(new { redirectUrl = redirectAfterCreate }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: _Есть 3 сущности - репетитор, студент, группа, все связаны друг с другом через многие ко многим._ Несколько сомнительный набор связей. Способный породить противоречивые соотношения. Экземпляр сущности Репетитор связан с экземпляром сущности Студент через экземпляр сущности Группа, но не связан напрямую - эти экземпляры зависимы или нет?

Comment: @Akina У **Репетитора** есть много групп и много студентов. **Студент** может обучаться у нескольких репетиторов и состоять в нескольких группах. **Группа** включает в себя несколько студентов и может пренадлежать одновременно нескольким репетиторам. Получается от каждой сущности две связи (типа многие-ко-многим) с двумя другими сущностями.

Comment: Не понимаю тонкостей предметной области, но чую, что где-то подвох. Больше всего мне не нравится сущность **Группа** - полное ощущение, что она избыточна и является на самом деле шаблоном/правилом, а не сущностью.

Comment: @Akina http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612586/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-3-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-entity-framework Взгляните пожалуйста, возможно Вы сможете что-то подсказать

Comment: Я понял, в чём подвох. В структуре не должны храниться отношения между С и Р, установленные на основании того, что оба эти экземпляра имеют атрибутом одну и ту же Г. Хранятся только соотношения Р-С, установленные напрямую, минуя Г. А реальное соотношение экземпляров Р-С (обучает или нет) вычисляется на основании данных таблицы прямых отношений и интерсекта частных отношений по таблице Г.

Comment: @Akina А как тогда быть со С, которые обучаются у репетитора, но не состоят ни в одной группе?

Comment: Для такой (и только такой) пары С-Р будет присутствовать запись в таблице связи Студент-Репетитор.

Comment: @Akina Я нашёл в чём была проблема. Спасибо, наверное Вы правы, вроде бы даже есть какой-то принцип не использовать избыточных связей, однако это сильно усложнит мои написанные запросы, поэтому оставлю в таком виде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось довольно просто, хоть и пришлось изрядно погуглить и поотлаживать. Темы сборщик мусора, виртуальные свойства EF, жизненный цикл контроллера ASP MVC 5.

Когда мы берём сущность: `var group = dbContext.Groups.First()` полученная сущность привязана к dbContext, т.е. он отслеживает объект который предоставил. В сущностях есть виртуальные свойства. Виртуальные свойства сразу не прогружены, в момент вызова `group.Tutors` происходит обращение к **контексту**, к которому привязана сущность и из него возвращается коллекция типа `Tutor`.

```
 groupForSave.Tutors = new List<Tutor>();
 groupForSave.Tutors.Add(tutorRepository.GetById(tutorId));
```

таким образом я получил в коллекции Tutors элемент, который завязан на контекст tutorRepository. И поэтому нельзя выполнить `groupRepository.Create(groupForSave)`, ведь в groupRepository есть свой контекст, попытка добавить в него tutor, который завязан на другой контекст приводит к ошибке.

Для исправления я решил, сделать свойство Context в репозиториях:

```
DbContext Context {
    get{return dbContext;}
    set{this.dbContext = value;}
}
```

Т.о. перед `groupRepository.Create(group)` я устанавливаю группам контекст из репетитора. Загвоздка в том, что экземпляр класса контроллера создаётся всякий раз при вызове метода действия, поэтому контекст репетиторской репозитории при добавлении не соответствует контексту репетиторского репозитория, который был использован для начальной инициализации поля group.Tutors. На старый контекст ссылается репетитор,поэтому контекст не был удалён сборщиком мусора, хотя экземпляр контроллера был уничтожен.

Решением стало объявление статической переменной contextForSave, которая инициилизируется нужным контекстом в методе Create и в последствии используется всякий раз при работе с groupRepository.  Также этот контекст по тем же причинам используется для studentRepository

кратко это выглядит так:

```
public class GroupController : Controller
{
    private GroupRepository groupRepository = new GroupRepository();
    private TutorRepository tutorRepository = new TutorRepository();
    private StudentRepository studentRepository = new StudentRepository();
    public static Group groupForSave;

    private static EFDbTutorProject contextForSave;
    public ActionResult Edit(int groupId, int tutorId)
    {
        contextForSave = tutorRepository.Context;
        groupRepository.Context = contextForSave; //as all classes have different context, we need one to detect modified students
        //...
    }


    public ActionResult Create(int groupId, int tutorId)
    {
        contextForSave = tutorRepository.Context;
        groupRepository.Context = contextForSave; //as all classes have different context, we need one to detect modified students
        //...
    }

    public ActionResult AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        //because id is 0 we should define if we need to create new student or it aleady exists in database
        studentRepository.Context = contextForSave;
        var stud = studentRepository.GetByMail(student.Email);
        //...
    }

    public JsonResult Save(Group group)
    {
        //return Json(group, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        groupForSave.Name = group.Name;
        groupRepository.CreateWithContext(groupForSave, contextForSave);
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Вы переусложнили свои репозитории. Просто принимайте контекст в конструкторе репозитория как параметр.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Добавил конструктор с параметром. Я не сильно усложнил свои репозитории, т.к. они унаследованы от абстрактного репозитория, понадобилось 4 строчки для свойства и 3 для второго конструктора :)