# Как организовать связи много-много для 3 связанных сущностей Entity Framework

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Есть репетитор, группа и студент.

Репетитор курирует несколько групп и студентов, если студент состоит в группе репетитора, то он является студентом данного репетитора.

Студент обучается у нескольких репетиторов и состоит в нескольких группах. Студент может обучаться у репетитора, но при этом не состоять ни в одной группе.

Группа курируется нескольким репетиторами и включает в себя много студентов.

```
class Group {
    public virtual List<Tutor> Tutors;
    public virtual List<Student>  Students;
}

class Student {
    public virtual List<Group> Groups;
    public virtual List<Tutor> Tutors;
}

class Tutor {
    public virtual List<Group> Groups;
    public virtual List<Student> Students;
}
```

Во-первых здесь сплошь и рядом циклические зависимости: `student.tutors[i].students[j].tutors[i].students[j]...`

Во-вторых, когда я пробую добавить новую группу падает ошибка, место отмечено в коде

**Метод create/update сущности Group**

```
    public override Group Create(Group obj)
    {
        Group dbEntry = dbContext.Groups.Include("Journals").Include("Students").Include("Tutors").Where(g => g.ID == obj.ID).FirstOrDefault();
        if(dbEntry != null)
        {
            var deletedTutors = dbEntry.Tutors.Except(obj.Tutors, tutor => tutor.ID).ToList<Tutor>();
            var addedTutors = obj.Tutors.Except(dbEntry.Tutors, tutor => tutor.ID).ToList<Tutor>();
            deletedTutors.ForEach(tutor=> dbEntry.Tutors.Remove(tutor));
            foreach (Tutor tutor in addedTutors)
            {
                dbEntry.Tutors.Add(tutor);
            }

            var deletedStudents = dbEntry.Students.Except(obj.Students, student => student.ID).ToList<Student>();
            var addedStudents = obj.Students.Except(dbEntry.Students, student => student.ID).ToList<Student>();
            deletedStudents.ForEach(student => dbEntry.Students.Remove(student));
            foreach (Student student in addedStudents)
            {
                dbEntry.Students.Add(student);
            }
            //if student below to group, he automatticaly belows to all tutors that are owners of group
            foreach(var student in dbEntry.Students)
            {
                var addedTutorsToStudent = dbEntry.Tutors.Except(student.Tutors, tutor => tutor.ID).ToList<Tutor>();
                foreach(var tutor in addedTutorsToStudent)
                {
                    student.Tutors.Add(tutor);
                }
            }
            dbEntry.Name = obj.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            dbContext.Groups.Add(obj); //!!!Здесь ошибка!!!
        }
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return obj;
    }
```

**Вот так я создаю объект типа Group**

```
public ActionResult Save(int tutorId) {
    groupForSave.Tutors.Add(tutorRepository.GetById(tutorId));
    groupRepository.Create(groupForSave);//что приводит к ошибке в методе Create см.выше
}
```

**ОШИБКА**

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker